# How to query array in document which contain specific values

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to query an array field in mongoose by an array.

**Code:**

```
const Test = mongoose.model('Test', new mongoose.Schema({ title: [Number] }));

await new Test({title: [20,30,40]}).save() // 1
await new Test({title: [40]}).save() // 2
await new Test({title: [10,30,40]}).save() // 3
await new Test({title: [20,30,40,90]}).save() // 4
await new Test({title: [30,40]}).save() // 5

const queryArray = [20, 30, 40];
const results = await Test.find({ title: queryArray }).lean();
console.log(results);
```

I want `results` to only return documents which `queryArray` contain. So if there's a value in the document that isn't in `queryResult`, that document shouldn't return.

In the code above, the first, second, and fifth document should return.

I thought of using `$in`, but that's goes through each item in the `queryArray` and that won't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ["$all"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) instead of ["$in"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/).

```
const results = await Test.find({ title: { $all: queryArray } }).lean();
```

Comment: Thanks John! When I do `$all`, I don't get the second document when `queryArray =  [20, 40]`

Comment: Ohm, sorry. I didn't read the question clearly enough. I'm not sure how to complete the request in a single query I'm afraid.